# unexpected token "indent" want to render on a jade file using node.js(app.js) and got this error 'unexpected token "indent" '

Tags: node.js, couchdb, pug

```
Error: E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\views\index.jade:3
    1| extend layout 

    2| 

  > 3|     block content

    4|         h1 Add to Contact

    5|         form(method='POST' ,action='/new_contact')

    6|         p Name:


unexpected token "indent"
    at Parser.parseExpr (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:254:15)
    at Parser.parse (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:122:25)
    at parse (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:104:21)
    at Object.exports.compile (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:205:16)
    at handleTemplateCache (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:174:25)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:380:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:370:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
    at View.render (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\Node.js\edureka\Example\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing should be indented under an `extends` statement. Instead, you should put the `block` statement on the same level as `extends`:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Add to Contact
  form(method='POST', action='/new_contact')
    p Name:
```